# Local_Auth FLUTTER PACKAGE

Tags: flutter, dart

The new version of [local_auth](https://pub.dev/packages/local_auth) flutter package only includes BiometricType.strong or BiometricType.weak.
Is there any way to detect fingerprint id and face id in android by using BiometricType.strong?

Comment: Read the metadata info properly ("Flutter plugin for Android and iOS devices to allow local authentication via fingerprint, touch ID, face ID, passcode, pin, or pattern.") link: https://pub.dev/packages/local_auth

Answer (score 0):

BiometricType.Strong is only supported on Google pixel because uses a "type" Class 3 authentication. The rest of androids and IOS uses BiometricType.Weak.